# Selecting features by id in activeLayer if I have txt file?

Tags: pyqgis

An example my txt files line is 3,6,7.

How do I select features in activeLayer with this ID in PyQGIS?

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() 

query ='"ID" = 3 or "ID" = 6 or "ID" = 7'

selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the text file into a list of ids using [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) then use IN operator instead of multiple OR to [select](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#selecting-features):

```
import csv

idlist = []
with open(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\ids.txt', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        idlist.extend(row)
idlist = [int(i) for i in idlist]
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression('"ID" IN{0}'.format(tuple(idlist)), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection) #Change "ID" to the name of your field
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give me ids.txt example maybe two or tree row

Comment: import csv
idlist = []

with open(r'Y:\Baze\test.txt', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        idlist.extend(row)

    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    layer.selectByExpression('"ID" IN{0}'.format(tuple(idlist)), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection) #Change "ID" to the name of your field
    
    newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Try without `newline=''`